# How to window.open in a new small div and not fullscreen?

Tags: javascript

https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/JjXOgKL

```
function downloadImg(id) {
  var image = list.$getRecord(id);
  // Window.open in a new div and not fullscreen
  window.open(image.url, 'Download');
}
```

When you click on download, the image will appear to be fullscreen but i want it to be in a small screen perhaps like a smalll div.
I have tried using "height=200,width=200" but no luck in doing so.
It would be great if you can provide a codepen demo. Thank you.

Comment: you want, maybe an `iframe`? rather than a window.open ... I think that's what you need

Comment: You want to open image in new different screen or want to show image on same page within a small div?

Comment: open image within a small div. Thank you

Comment: I tried so many times still cannot

Comment: and same page too

Comment: @MaximusSu how about opening in a modal ? let me know

Comment: are you trying to accomplish a popup modal? that would be accomplished using css `z-index`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping. Ok sure anything that makes it small and not fullscree.

Comment: pop up box will do too. But its quite complicated

Comment: no. I have tried it already.